# Executing (jar file ) Batch script from c#

Tags: c#, selenium, jar, batch-file, executable-jar

I have a batch script containing a selenium jar file. I want to execute the batch script from C#. May I know how it is possible.

example.bat

> java -jar "path to selenium jar"

I want to execute  this example.bat from C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process and ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)

Pur your java command, or your batch file name in the `command` String.

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

// Get the output into a string
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// Display the command output.
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you want to run it asynchronously, try with this :

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute the command Asynchronously.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="command">string command.</param>
public void ExecuteCommandAsync(string command)
{
   try
   {
    //Asynchronously start the Thread to process the Execute command request.
    Thread objThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteCommandSync));
    //Make the thread as background thread.
    objThread.IsBackground = true;
    //Set the Priority of the thread.
    objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
    //Start the thread.
    objThread.Start(command);
   }
   catch (ThreadStartException objException)
   {
    // Log the exception
   }
   catch (ThreadAbortException objException)
   {
    // Log the exception
   }
   catch (Exception objException)
   {
    // Log the exception
   }
}
```

Comment: But the jar is not running, the command prompt is shutting off

Comment: @saisindhu Put CreateNoWindow = false, and tell us what you see.

Comment: @saisindhu I added the ouput, it should be written in your Console. It will help see what happens too.

Comment: @saisindhu added another way to do it, with a different Thread.

Comment: @saisindhu /c tells the cmd that it must wait for parameters. It's after /C that you put the path to your batch file so that it's executed.

Comment: Individually the batch file is executing fine. But unable to run from C#. It is a jar file which has to run continiusly. Not just run and exit. Please help

Comment: @saisindhu If you do it with the asynchronous way I added in my answer, it should do the trick.

Comment: May I know what this line is Thread objThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteCommandSync));

Comment: @saisindhu This line creates the separate Thread executing your command.